# How to make toggles non-changeable while mounting the menu?

Tags: reactjs, menu, accordion, togglebutton

I would like to know how can we make a toggle, which wouldn't have changed its state after the menu is mounted again. Down below there is a gif, which illustrates what I have at the moment. I don't want the toggle to be unchecked after I show the menu again.
[image: example of what I have]

**ToggleButton**

```
export const ToggleButton = ({id}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(toggleReducer, TOGGLE_INITIAL)
    const {manageToggles} = useContext(MapContext)

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const action = {
            type: ACTIONS_TOGGLE.CHANGE_TOGGLE,
            payload: {
                id: id,
                value: e.target.checked
            }
        }
        manageToggles(toggleReducer(state, action))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="checkbox" id={id} className={styles.toggleCheckbox} onChange={handleChange}  />
            <label htmlFor={id}></label>
        </>
    )
}
```

**CompoundComponent**

```
export const CompoundComponent = () => {
  return (
    <MenuAccordion>
      <MenuAccordion.Group title={'Социальная инфраструктура'}>
        <MenuAccordion.Item title={'Промышленные зоны'} id={"promZones"} />
        <MenuAccordion.Item title={'Жилые зоны'} id={"livingZones"}/>
      </MenuAccordion.Group>
  )
}
```

**MenuAccordion.Group**

```
MenuAccordion.Group = function MenuGroup({ children, title }) {
  const { activeGroup, switchGroup } = useContext(MenuContext);

  return (
      <button onClick={() => {switchGroup(title)}}></button>
      <div>{children}</div>
  );
};
```

**MenuAccordion.Item**

```
MenuAccordion.Item = function MenuItem({ title, id }) {
  return (
    <span className={styles.itemBox}>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <ToggleButton title={title} id={id}/>
    </span>
  );
};
```

**MenuAccordion**

```
const MenuAccordion = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeGroup, setActiveGroup] = useState(undefined);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const switchGroup = useCallback(title => {
    setActiveGroup(activeTitle => {
      return activeTitle === title ? undefined : title;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MenuContext.Provider value={{ activeGroup, switchGroup, show, setShow }}>
      {children}
    </MenuContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Is there any way to use memoization or something like this?